# design pattern for parsing object to specific model and vice versa

Tags: oop, design-patterns, serialization

I have a file uploading logic and a very specific business rules. And according them I should parse my filemodel to row, which looks like "Header:{processed field1},{processed field2},{processed field3},{processed field4},{processed field5},{processed field6},{processed field7},{processed field8} and so on for 19 params" It's initially custom serialization.

And I also should have possibility to parse this row back to object. So, the question is what is a common idea to codding such staff?

Because now for parsing model to row I just use string.format with many options, and for parsing row to model I split the row by ',' and then manipulation with parts of information assign it to models fields. But in this implementation there are a lot of low level work, some hard coded position and also a lot of things that do not look pretty for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your serialization / deserialization inside a custom serializer. You can follow the same pattern as the other serializers in the .net library and implement the `IFormatter` [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iformatter.aspx) . This would provide you with a common interface that you can use to stream to and from a file (or any stream):

```cs
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    var formatter = new CustomFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream, objectToSerialize);
}

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Read))
{
    var formatter = new CustomFormatter();
    return (CustomType)formatter.DeSerialize(fileStream);
}
```

You can see an example of a [custom formatter](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/SafeFormatter.zip) in this download

Answer (score 2):

There's not going to be any magic involved here, particularly since you are serializing the object to a non standard format. You're probably going to have to live with the 'ugly' code.

Comment: Yes, looks like that. And I don't like it - thats why I'm asking.